# Toasted Notification with progressbar update not working

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, toast

To keep toasted notifications visible on screen i am create a toast notification of type

```
Scenario = ToastScenario.Reminder
```

First i create a toast notification in main thread by using `CoreDispatcher` object and then i use a timer to update the progressbar on my toast notification.
All the update i am doing via `CoreDispatcher` object.

First time it works fine. 
When i make any request which causes to display new toast notification, first i hide the old notification by using `ToastNotificationManager.History.Remove(TAG,GROUP);` method and then I show the new toast notification.

After hiding the second toast I enable the first toast notification again. So first i call the show to display the first toast notification again then i enable the timer which sends the update on toast notification in the same way as i was doing in the first place.

Problem is, when my toast notification appears in the screen again it continuously come and go away. I can see continuous flickering of toast notification.
This case is happening only when i set `Scenario` to `ToastScenario.Reminder`.

For default `Scenario` it works fine.

What exactly i am doing wrong in-case of `ToastScenario.Reminder`.

Required code

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }
        private void RegisterBackgroundTasks()
        {
            const string taskName = "ToastBackgroundTask";

            // If background task is already registered, then unregister it
            foreach (var bgTask in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (bgTask.Value.Name == taskName)
                {
                    bgTask.Value.Unregister(true);
                }
            }

            // Create the background task
            BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder()
            {
                Name = taskName,
            };

            // Assign the toast action trigger
            builder.SetTrigger(new ToastNotificationActionTrigger());

            // And register the task
            BackgroundTaskRegistration registration = builder.Register();
        }
        protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            RegisterBackgroundTasks();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
            {
                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                    // parameter
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
                }
                // Ensure the current window is active
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
            RegisterBackgroundTasks();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">


    <StackPanel>
        <Button  Width="200" Height="200" Click="Button_Click">Progress Bar Toast</Button>
        <Button  Width="200" Height="200" Click="Button_Click_1">Text Toast</Button>

    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

**MainPage.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;


// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Timer  playingTimeElapsedTimer;
        CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher;
        static NotificationManager aNotificationManager = new NotificationManager();
        public MainPage()
        {

            this.InitializeComponent();
            playingTimeElapsedTimer = new Timer(500);
            playingTimeElapsedTimer.Elapsed += PlayingTimeElapsedTimer_Elapsed;
        }


        private void PlayingTimeElapsedTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            //Task.Run(()=> {
            //  coreDispatcher.TryRunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            //{
            //System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            //{
                PlayerNotificationMessage aPlayerNotificationMessage = CreatToast();
                aNotificationManager.UpdatePlayerToastNotification(aPlayerNotificationMessage);
            //});
            //t1.Start();
            if (count == Total)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        }


        double count = 0;
        double Total = 1000;

        private PlayerNotificationMessage CreatToast() {

            PlayerNotificationMessage aPlayerNotificationMessage = new PlayerNotificationMessage()
            {
                PlayPauseImage = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/master/build/nuget.png",
                PlayPauseText = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/master/build/nuget.png",
                SongImageUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/master/build/nuget.png",
                NotificationMessage = new Windows.UI.Notifications.NotificationData()
                {
                    //SequenceNumber =0,
                    Values = {
                     { "progressValue", Math.Round(count/Total,2).ToString() },

                    { "progressValueString", count.ToString()+"/"+Total },
                    { "progressStatus", "" },
                    { "songTitle", "pawan" },
                    { "songTitle1", "tiwari" },
                    { "songTitle2", "test" },
                    }
                }

            };
            return aPlayerNotificationMessage;
        }
        private   void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {

                PlayerNotificationMessage aPlayerNotificationMessage = CreatToast();
                aNotificationManager.ShowPlayerToastNotification(aPlayerNotificationMessage);

                playingTimeElapsedTimer.Start();
            //});
            //t.Start();



        }

        private void  Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                    NotificationMessage aPlayerNotificationMessage = new NotificationMessage();
                    aNotificationManager.ShowCards(aPlayerNotificationMessage);

        }


    }
}
```

**PlayerNotificationMessage**

```
using Microsoft.QueryStringDotNET;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;

namespace App2
{
    public class PlayerNotificationMessage : NotificationMessage
    {

        public NotificationData NotificationMessage { get; set; }
        public string SongImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string PlayPauseText { get; set; }
        public string PlayPauseImage { get; set; }

        public override ToastContent CreateToastedContent()
        {
            return new ToastContent
            {
                //Scenario is type of call, so that user can not dismiss the music player on lock screen.
                Scenario = ToastScenario.Reminder,
                Launch = "action=dismiss",
                ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background,
                Audio = new ToastAudio() { Silent = true },
                Visual = new ToastVisual
                {
                    BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric
                    {
                        Children =
                        {
                            new AdaptiveText()
                            {
                                HintWrap = false,
                                HintMaxLines = 1,
                                HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Title,
                                Text = new BindableString("songTitle")
                            },
                            new AdaptiveText
                            {
                                HintWrap = false,
                                HintMaxLines = 1,
                                HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Caption,
                                Text =  new BindableString("songTitle1")
                            },
                            new AdaptiveProgressBar()
                            {
                                Title = new BindableString("songTitle2"),
                                Value = new BindableProgressBarValue("progressValue"),
                                ValueStringOverride = new BindableString("progressValueString"),
                                Status = new BindableString("progressStatus")
                            }
                        },

                        AppLogoOverride = new ToastGenericAppLogo()
                        {
                            AlternateText = new BindableString("songTitle"),
                            Source = SongImageUrl
                        },
                        HeroImage = new ToastGenericHeroImage()
                        {
                            Source = SongImageUrl,
                            AlternateText = new BindableString("songTitle"),

                        }
                    }
                },
                Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
                {
                    Buttons =
                    {
                        new ToastButton("Prev", new QueryString()
                        {
                            { "action", "previous" }

                        }.ToString() )
                        {
                                ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background,
                                ActivationOptions = new ToastActivationOptions()
                                {
                                    AfterActivationBehavior = ToastAfterActivationBehavior.PendingUpdate
                            },
                            ImageUri = SongImageUrl,


                        },
                        new ToastButton(PlayPauseText, new QueryString()
                        {
                            { "action", PlayPauseText }

                        }.ToString() )
                        {
                            ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background,
                            ActivationOptions = new ToastActivationOptions()
                            {
                                AfterActivationBehavior = ToastAfterActivationBehavior.PendingUpdate
                            },
                            ImageUri = PlayPauseImage

                        },
                        new ToastButton("Next", new QueryString()
                        {
                            { "action", "next" }

                        }.ToString() )
                        {
                            ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background,
                            ActivationOptions = new ToastActivationOptions()
                            {
                                AfterActivationBehavior = ToastAfterActivationBehavior.PendingUpdate
                            },
                            ImageUri = SongImageUrl
                        },

                    },
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**NotificationMessage, IToastNotification, AudioPlayerNotifier**

```
using Microsoft.QueryStringDotNET;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;

namespace App2
{
    public  class NotificationMessage
    {
        public string Image => "https://cdn.builtinseattle.com/sites/www.builtinseattle.com/files/styles/company_logo/public/2018-06/Drift.png";
        /// <summary>
        /// Notification Tag identifier for toasted notification. 
        /// </summary>
        public string Tag => "TAG";
        /// <summary>
        /// Notification Group identifier for toasted notification. 
        /// </summary>
        public string Group => "GROUP";
        /// <summary>
        /// Create Toast notification object of give data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Toast content XML</returns>
        public virtual ToastContent CreateToastedContent() {
            ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
            {
                Launch = "app-defined-string",
                Duration = ToastDuration.Long,
                //ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background,
                Scenario = ToastScenario.Reminder,
                Visual = new ToastVisual()
                {
                    BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                    {
                        Children =
    {
        new AdaptiveText()
        {
            Text =  new BindableString("text"),
            HintMaxLines = 1
        },

        new AdaptiveText()
        {
            Text =  new BindableString("text")
        },

        new AdaptiveText()
        {
            Text = new BindableString("text")
        },

    },AppLogoOverride = new ToastGenericAppLogo() {
        Source = this.Image
    }
                    }
                },


            };
            return content;
        }

    }
    public interface IToastNotification<T> where T : NotificationMessage
    {
        void Show(T aNotificationMessage);
        void Update(T aNotificationMessage);
        void Hide();
    }
    public class AudioPlayerNotifier : IToastNotification<PlayerNotificationMessage>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Toast notifier
        /// </summary>
        private ToastNotifier toastNotifier;
        private PlayerNotificationMessage aPlayerNotificationMessage;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public AudioPlayerNotifier()
        {
            toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Hide toast notification.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="toastNotification"></param>
        public void Hide()
        {
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Show the Audio Player toast notification.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aNotificationModel"></param>
        public void Show(PlayerNotificationMessage aPlayerNotificationMessage)
        {
            var toastContent = aPlayerNotificationMessage.CreateToastedContent();
            var toastNotification = new ToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml())
            {
                Tag = aPlayerNotificationMessage.Tag,
                Group = aPlayerNotificationMessage.Group,
                Data = aPlayerNotificationMessage.NotificationMessage,
            };
            toastNotification.Dismissed += ToastNotification_Dismissed;
            this.aPlayerNotificationMessage = aPlayerNotificationMessage;
            this.toastNotifier.Show(toastNotification);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        private void ToastNotification_Dismissed(ToastNotification sender, ToastDismissedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Reason == ToastDismissalReason.UserCanceled || args.Reason == ToastDismissalReason.TimedOut)
            {
                this.Show(aPlayerNotificationMessage);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update music player timeline.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aNotificationMessage"></param>
        public void Update(PlayerNotificationMessage aNotificationMessage)
        {
            this.toastNotifier.Update(aNotificationMessage.NotificationMessage, aNotificationMessage.Tag, aNotificationMessage.Group);
        }
    }
}
```

**CardsNotifier**

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;

namespace App2
{
    internal class CardsNotifier : IToastNotification<NotificationMessage>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Toast notifier
        /// </summary>
        private ToastNotifier toastNotifier;

        private ToastNotification toastedNotification;

        public CardsNotifier()
        {
            toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        }
        public void Hide()
        {

        }

        public void Show(NotificationMessage aNotificationMessage)
        {
            ToastContent toastContent = aNotificationMessage.CreateToastedContent();
            //show the notification.
            toastedNotification = new ToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml())
            {
                Tag = aNotificationMessage.Tag,
                Group = aNotificationMessage.Group,
            };
            this.toastNotifier.Show(toastedNotification);
        }

        public void Update(NotificationMessage aNotificationMessage)
        {
            //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**NotificationManager**

```
public class NotificationManager
    {
        private IToastNotification<PlayerNotificationMessage> audioPlayerNotifier;
        private IToastNotification<NotificationMessage> cardsNotifier;

        private const string TAG = "TAG";
        private const string GROUP = "GROUP";
        private ToastNotifier toastNotifier;
        private bool IsPlayerActive = false;
        public NotificationManager( IToastNotification<PlayerNotificationMessage> audioPlayerNotifier, IToastNotification<NotificationMessage> cardsNotifier)
        {
            toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
            this.audioPlayerNotifier = audioPlayerNotifier;
            this.cardsNotifier = cardsNotifier;
        }

        public NotificationManager()
        {
            toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();

            this.audioPlayerNotifier = new AudioPlayerNotifier();
            this.cardsNotifier = new CardsNotifier();
        }

        public void HideNotification()
        {
            ToastNotificationManager.History.Remove(TAG, GROUP);
            //ToastNotificationManager.History.Clear();
            //this.cardsNotifier.Hide();
            //this.audioPlayerNotifier.Hide();
        }

        public void ShowCards(NotificationMessage notificationMessage)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("####ShowCards");
            this.HideNotification();
            IsPlayerActive = false;
            cardsNotifier.Show(notificationMessage);
        }

        public void ShowPlayerToastNotification(PlayerNotificationMessage aNotificationModel)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("####ShowPlayerToastNotification");
            this.HideNotification();
            IsPlayerActive = true;
            this.audioPlayerNotifier.Show(aNotificationModel);
        }

        private object lockObject = new object();
        public void UpdatePlayerToastNotification(PlayerNotificationMessage aNotificationViewModel)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (!IsPlayerActive)
                {
                    IsPlayerActive = true;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("####UpdatePlayerToastNotification");
                    //If player is not active, only update toast will not work.
                    //First we need to show the toast notification.
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Date before "+System.DateTime.Now);
                    //this.ShowPlayerToastNotification(aNotificationViewModel);
                    //Task.Delay(10).Wait();
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Date after"+System.DateTime.Now);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.audioPlayerNotifier.Update(aNotificationViewModel);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To reproduce the issue please toggle between ProgressBar toast and Text toast (toggle multiple times then you will see ProgressBar  toast starts blink ). Start with ProgressBar Toast.
Sorry for some crappy code, i am not sure why it was not reproducing initially.

Comment: Could you share a code sample that could reproduce this issue. I will test.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I am trying to create a sample code to reproduce the same issue but in sample code it's rarely reproducing.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Can repro the issue?

Comment: I tried your code, unfortunately, I could not reproduce your issue.

Comment: First click the Text toast button then progressbar toast button. Toggle in between then and you will see that progressbar toast will start flicking. If i removed the progressbar from toast xml then everything works fine.

Comment: Give 2 or 3 sec between toggling

Comment: I mean I could not create a complete project with your code,I miss some class `NotificationManager`  and `QueryString` .

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have added NotificationManager class, for QueryString, please run Install-Package QueryString.NET -Version 1.0.0 command

Comment: For simplicity, if you change the Scenario to ToastScenario.Default then first click the ProgressBar Toast then Text toast and then click again the ProgressBar Toast. Ideally progress bar toast should display the progress value but it doesn't show any progress and after 7 sec it hides then appear again with updated value. After that it works fine. This is the case with ToastScenario.Default. For ToastScenario.Remainder, I am still facing the same flickering issue.

Comment: I have added code example to repro the another issue with toast notifications on MSDN forum, can you please have a look to it.

Comment: I tested your code, and progressbar works well, I can reproduce continuous flickering of toast notification. And I have checked your code. I found you show the toast in the `ToastNotification_Dismissed` event handler. Could you tell the reason why do this?

Comment: I tried the same code without the ToastNotification_Dismissed still i can face the same issue.
BTW purpose of  the ToastNotification_Dismissed is to Show toast again if user close it or it expires.

Comment: As I mentioned, that I am f facing the flickering issue only when I use ToastScenario.Remainder Toast. In case of ToastScenario.Default toast, after switching from different toast to toast with progressbar, does not receive any update. Once it expired ToastNotification_Dismissed opens it again then it shows progress.
You can simple create two toast one with progressbar and one without. After you switch pack to progressbar again it won't show progress anymore

Comment: BTW mostly I am using that toast notification when windows is locked but same issue is happening even when windows is unlocked

Comment: Are you able to repro the issue?

Comment: I have tried modify the `ToastScenario` as default.  but the issue also exist. if I remove  `ToastNotification_Dismissed` the project works well.

Comment: For me even I remove ToastNotification_Dismissed it doesn't work always, Issue is intermittent but once occurs then it always occurs.
BTW is there any way to support BindableString for image source also, if not how tough if will be to implement it?

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-progress-bar#using-data-binding-to-update-a-toast), Have you add SequenceNumber for the new   NotificationData ?  *BTW is there any way to support BindableString for image* Pleas check [Toast content schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-schema), AdaptiveImage  Source property does not support bindable. So you could not update it with NotificationData instance.

Comment: Yes, I did added incremental Sequence number and Sequence number with always 0, also. In both the cases i am getting same error.

Comment: Are you able to re-pro the issue without Dismiss event.

Comment: I could not reproduce with out dismiss event.